# How to change the selection color in an NSTextView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit, nstextview

I'm using SwiftUI and NSViewRepresentable to create a custom NSTextView that can display selectable text. Here's my code:

```
struct SelectableText: NSViewRepresentable {
    let text: String
    let font: NSFont?
    
    init(text: String, font: NSFont? = nil) {
        self.text = text
        self.font = font
    }
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSTextField {
        let textField = NSTextField(wrappingLabelWithString: text)
        textField.isBezeled = false
        textField.isEditable = false
        textField.isSelectable = true
        textField.backgroundColor = .clear
        textField.font = font ?? NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: NSFont.systemFontSize)
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextField, context: Context) {
        nsView.stringValue = text
        nsView.font = font ?? NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: NSFont.systemFontSize)
    }
}
```

I want to change the color of the selection highlight in the NSTextView. I tried setting the selectedTextAttributes property, but it didn't work as expected. The NSTextView is not receiving the events it needs to handle text selection correctly.

How can I change the selection color in an NSTextView in SwiftUI? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe the `NSTextField` class does not provide a direct way to change the colour of the selection highlight. The system determines the selection highlight color and cannot be easily customized for an `NSTextField`

Comment: Please not that your question you are talking about `NSTextView` while your code uses `NSTextField` which is confusing

Comment: @cedricbahirwe, thank you for your comments. I apologize for the confusion. I initially used NSTextField in my code, but I was advised to switch to NSTextView to change the selection highlight color. However, the solution provided didn't work as expected. I understand that NSTextField and NSTextView have different properties and behaviors, and I'm trying to find a solution that allows me to change the selection highlight color in a text field or text view within SwiftUI. Any further advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant `NSTextView`, here is a possible approach:

```swift
struct SelectableTextView: NSViewRepresentable {
    let text: String
    let font: NSFont?
    
    init(text: String, font: NSFont? = nil) {
        self.text = text
        self.font = font
    }
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSTextView {
        let textView = NSTextView(frame: .zero)
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear
        textView.font = font ?? NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: NSFont.systemFontSize)
        textView.string = text
        
        textView.selectedTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : NSColor.systemGreen, // Change the text color
            NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: NSColor.systemRed// Change the background color
        ]
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextView, context: Context) {
        nsView.string = text
        nsView.font = font ?? NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: NSFont.systemFontSize)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried implementing this solution in my code, but unfortunately, it didn't work as expected. The text in the NSTextView is no longer selectable, and the selection highlight color did not change to the specified colors. I'm using NSTextView within SwiftUI via NSViewRepresentable, and I'm trying to change the selection highlight color. If there's something I might be missing or if you have any other suggestions, I would greatly appreciate your further assistance.

Comment: Which `macOS` version are you targeting ?

Comment: You can check the demo [here](https://github.com/cedricbahirwe/NSTextViewDemo), working on `macOS 13.1`

Comment: Your github repo helped a lot thanks!, but I have another issue related to this question. Here is it -- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76443563/swift-chat-app-messages-generated-upwards-and-overlapping-how-to-resolve)