# Swift Chat App: Messages Generated Upwards and Overlapping - How to Resolve?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, chat

I'm currently working on a chat application in Swift using SwiftUI. I've run into an issue with message generation: they are generated upwards, and one text overlaps another one. Another problem is that the height of the messages frames are fixed. Below is my code for the message row view:

````js
struct SelectableTextView: NSViewRepresentable {
  let text: String
  let font: NSFont ?

    init(text: String, font: NSFont ? = nil) {
      self.text = text
      self.font = font
    }

  func makeNSView(context: Context) - > NSTextView {
    let textView = NSTextView(frame: .zero)
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.isSelectable = true
    textView.backgroundColor = .clear
    textView.font = font ? ? NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: NSFont.systemFontSize)
    textView.string = text

    textView.selectedTextAttributes = [
      NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor.systemGreen, // Change the text color
      NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: NSColor.systemRed // Change the background color
    ]
    return textView
  }

  func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextView, context: Context) {
    nsView.string = text
    nsView.font = font ? ? NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: NSFont.systemFontSize)
  }
}

struct MessageRowView: View {

  @Environment(\.colorScheme) private
  var colorScheme
  let message: MessageRow
  let retryCallback: (MessageRow) - > Void

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
      HStack {
        Text("You").font(.system(size: 16)).padding(.leading).padding(.top).bold()
        Spacer()
      }

      messageRow(text: message.sendText, image: message.sendImage, bgColor: colorScheme == .light ? .white : Color(red: 52 / 255, green: 53 / 255, blue: 65 / 255, opacity: 0))

      if let text = message.responseText {
        Divider()
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          HStack {
            Text("AI")
              .font(.system(size: 16))
              .bold()
              .background(
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.orange]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
              )
              .mask(
                Text("AI")
                .font(.system(size: 16))
                .bold()
              )
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "doc.on.clipboard")
              .resizable()
              .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
              .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
              .padding(.trailing)
              .onTapGesture {
                copyToClipboard(text: text)
              }
              .opacity(0.7)
          }
          .padding(.leading)
            .padding(.top)
          messageRow(text: text, image: message.responseImage, bgColor: .gray.opacity(0), responseError: message.responseError, showDotLoading: message.isInteractingWithChatGPT)

          Divider()
        }
      }
    }
  }

  func messageRow(text: String, image: String, bgColor: Color, responseError: String ? = nil, showDotLoading : Bool = false) - > some View {
    let components = text.split(separator: "```", omittingEmptySubsequences: false)
    return VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ForEach(0.. < components.count, id: \.self) {
          index in
            let component = String(components[index])
          if index % 2 == 1 { // Code block
            let lines = component.split(separator: "\n", omittingEmptySubsequences: false)
            if let firstLine = lines.first,
              lines.count > 1 {
                let restOfCode = lines[1...].joined(separator: "\n")
                CardView(title: String(firstLine), bodyText: restOfCode)
                  .padding()
              }
          } else { // Normal text
            SelectableTextView(text: component).frame(width: 400, height: 100)
          }
        }
      }
      .padding(16)
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
      .background(bgColor)
  }
}
````

Is there a way to generate the messages downwards instead of upwards and make it scroll down automatically? Also, how can I make the height of the message frames dynamic rather than fixed? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It is hard to provide Minimal Reproducible Example, but I can provide some screenshots or video recordings will this be helpful?

Comment: see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Screenshots or recordings won't be helpful. As to it being hard to provide an MRE, who should be doing that work? The person asking, or the volunteers just trying to help?

Comment: Ok I'll try to provide MRE thanks.